# how to create the product of many columns into new columns pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `pandas` data frame:

```
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.DataFrame({'dummy_1' : [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                    'dummy_2' : [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                    'dummy_3' : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]})
```

I would like to add as new columns (in the same dataframe) the product, the product with each column, with the other two.

So that the resulting dataframe, looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({     'dummy_1' : [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                        'dummy_2' : [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                        'dummy_3' : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                        'dummy_12' :[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                        'dummy_13' :[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                        'dummy_23' :[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this ? And by efficient I mean a way that would work for e.g. 50 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations` to get all combinations and iterate through those combinations to compute the vectorized product and assign to the new column

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
df = pd.DataFrame({'dummy_1' : [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                'dummy_2' : [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                'dummy_3' : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]})
for i in combinations(df.columns, 2):
    col_name = i[0] + i[1].split('_')[-1]
    df[col_name] = df[i[0]] * df[i[1]]
```

Output

```
dummy_1 dummy_2 dummy_3 dummy_12    dummy_13    dummy_23
0       1       1       0           0           1
0       1       1       0           0           1
0       0       1       0           0           0
1       0       0       0           0           0
1       1       0       1           0           0
0       1       0       0           0           0
```

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dummy_1' : [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                    'dummy_2' : [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                    'dummy_3' : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]})

df['dummy_12'] = df['dummy_1']*df['dummy_2']
df['dummy_13'] = df['dummy_1']*df['dummy_3']
df['dummy_23'] = df['dummy_2']*df['dummy_3']

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    dummy_1  dummy_2  dummy_3  dummy_12  dummy_13  dummy_23                                                                                     
0        0        1        1         0         0         1                                                                                     
1        0        1        1         0         0         1                                                                                     
2        0        0        1         0         0         0                                                                                     
3        1        0        0         0         0         0                                                                                     
4        1        1        0         1         0         0                                                                                     
5        0        1        0         0         0         0
```

Comment: I am looking for a way that would work for e.g. 50 columns

Comment: see @mad_ 's solution. It is more generic.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your needs without requiring any additional imports, just change the maximum range of i and j to use it on a larger dataframe (for example 50).

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(i + 1, 3):
        df['dummy_%d%d' %(i+1, j+1)] = df.apply(lambda x: x[i] * x[j], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   dummy_1  dummy_2  dummy_3  dummy_12  dummy_13  dummy_23                                                                                     
0        0        1        1         0         0         1                                                                                     
1        0        1        1         0         0         1                                                                                     
2        0        0        1         0         0         0                                                                                     
3        1        0        0         0         0         0                                                                                     
4        1        1        0         1         0         0                                                                                     
5        0        1        0         0         0         0
```